# discord.py How to get logs from a DM channel

Tags: python, python-3.5, discord

I'm trying to detect whether the last message my bot has sent to a user is identical to the one it needs to send (Python 3.5).

I've tried to use `client.logs_from(channel,limit=1)` but I'm not sure how to make it get the logs from a DM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`client.logs_from`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.logs_from) accepts a [PrivateChannel](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#privatechannel) instance to its channel argument. Assuming you know which user's PM channel you want to check already (and it sounds like you do), it's as simple as:

```
# PrivateChannel instance is privateCh

newMsg = 'your message here'
async for msg in client.log_from(privateCh, limit=1):
    if newMsg != msg.content:
        await client.send_message(privateCh, newMsg)
```

Comment: but what should I define privateCh as? (`NameError: name 'privateCh' is not defined`)

Comment: Ah, yeah, you need to get the user's PM channel somehow and define it first. For now you'll need to loop through `client.private_channels` to find the one with the target user in `privatechannel.recipients`. In the next version you can just do `user.dm_channel` to get it.